# Vertx - stop method in verticle is not guaranteed

Tags: vert.x, vertx-verticle

If you run the following code multiple times you will see the inconsistency: some times there are 3 lines displayed, some times there are only 2 lines displayed (the one missing is "Successfully stopped MyVerticle"). Why the .stop method is not called?

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
        vertx.rxDeployVerticle(new MyVerticle()).subscribe();
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(
                new Thread(() -> {
                    //vertx.deploymentIDs().forEach( deploymentId -> vertx.undeploy(deploymentId));
                    vertx.close(result -> System.out.println("Result" + result));
                    System.out.println("Successfully stopped Vertx");
                })
        );
    }
}

class MyVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

    @Override
    public void start(Future<Void> startFuture) {
        System.out.println("Successfully started MyVerticle");
        startFuture.complete();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop(Future<Void> stopFuture) {
        System.out.println("Successfully stopped MyVerticle");
        stopFuture.complete();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `stop()` is invoked when Vert.x undeploys a verticle.

When terminating your application, Vert.x will attempt to undeploy the verticles as well, but it's a race between event loop still running and your application shutting down.

Comment: Not exactly, `stop()` is invoked by Vert.x when the verticle is undeployed. It's not to be called by the user. The issue here is that `Vertx#close` is an asynchronous operation so there is no guarantee that the callback is invoked before the hook is finished. There should be a latch or something to wait for the result.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I reread my answer and it is indeed not clear what I meant.